# Copiar dados de um novo registro MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um pequeno problema ao tentar fazer com que um registro novo seja incluído em outra tabela, ou seja:

Tenho uma tabela-A no banco com as colunas:

```
id | nome | email | tel | campanha
```

na tabela-B tenho as colunas:

```
id | id-tabela-A | valores
```

resumindo, não sei por onde começar, mas basicamente é pegar a id da tabela-A e incluir ela na tabela-B dentro da coluna id-tabela-A, é possível fazer isso com PHP?

```
<?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    $nome_usuario = $_POST['nome'];
    $email_usuario = $_POST['email'];
    $tel_usuario = $_POST['telefone'];
    $fonte_usuario = $_POST['fonte'];

    $status_usuario = "2"; //Definir ( 1 - Cliente, 2 - Prospect, 3 - Contato Inicial, 4 - Sem contato, 5 - Enviada a proposta, 6 - Sem contato )

    // CAMPANHA
    $campanha_valor = "CAMPANHA EBOOK"; // NOME DA CAMPANHA
    $campanha_id = "1"; //ID CAMPO CAMPANHA

    // tereriano ?
    $tereriano_usuario = $_POST['checagem'];
    $tereriano_id = "2"; //ID CAMPO VOCENIADO

    $nome_usuario = mysql_escape_string($nome_usuario);
    $email_usuario = mysql_escape_string($email_usuario);
    $tel_usuario = mysql_escape_string($tel_usuario);

    //$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, email) VALUES ('$nome_usuario','$email_usuario')";
    $result_usuario = "INSERT INTO tblleads('name',assigned, 'status', source, email, phonenumber, campanha, tereriano) VALUES ('$nome_usuario',RecuperaProximoAssigned(),'$status_usuario','$fonte_usuario','$email_usuario','$tel_usuario','$campanha_id','$tereriano_usuario')";

    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario); //EXECUTA

    //$lastID = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // ID DO REGISTRO GERADO
    //obtem o último ID duma instrução INSERT
    $lastID = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");

    $result_usuario_2 = "INSERT INTO tblcustomfieldsvalues(relid,fieldid,fieldto,value) VALUES ('$lastID','$tereriano_id',leads, '$tereriano_usuario')"; //INSERE O tereriano

    mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario_2); //EXECUTA

    $result_usuario_3 = "INSERT INTO tblcustomfieldsvalues(relid,fieldid,fieldto,'value') VALUES ('$lastID','$campanha_id',leads, '$campanha_valor')"; //INSERE A CAMPANHA

    mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario_3); //EXECUTA

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0){
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=#'>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('E-mail cadastrado com Sucesso.');
                    </script>
                ";    
            }else{
                echo "
                    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=#'>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        alert('Houve algum erro!.');
                    </script>
                ";    
            }

//CREATE FUNCTION RecuperaProximoAssigned ()
//RETURNS INT RETURN (
//    CASE
//       WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblleads) = 0 THEN 1
//       WHEN (SELECT assigned FROM tblleads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) = 5 THEN 1
//       ELSE (SELECT assigned FROM tblleads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) + 1
//   END
//  );
?>
```

Comment: quando você insere na `tabela-A` precisa ir no bd.. por que não aproveita o acesso à base e já cria o _insert_ na `tabela-B`?

Comment: fiz uma alteração, disponibilizei o codigo para melhor entendimento.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Copiar registro de uma tabela para outra MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362185/copiar-registro-de-uma-tabela-para-outra-mysql)

Comment: Você quer retornar o ultimo ID inserido na tabela A e inseri-lo na tabela B ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo, acredito que com isso consiga ter uma ideia.

```
<?php
/* tentativa de conexão com o servidor MySQL. Assumindo que você está executando o MySQL
servidor com configuração padrão (usuário 'root' sem senha) */

//$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo', 'db_demo');
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_demo');

// verifica a conexão
if($conn === false){
    die("ERROR: Não foi possível conectar. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// tentativa para inserir execução de consulta
$query = "INSERT INTO tabela_a (nome, email, telefone) VALUES ('Joãozinho', 'joaozinho@email.com', '31999887766')";

//$sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
//$last_id = mysql_insert_id($conn);

if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
    // obtém o último ID inserido
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $query_2 = "INSERT INTO tabela_b (nome, email, telefone, tabela_a_id) VALUES ('Joãozinho', 'joaozinho@email.com', '31999887766', $last_id)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query_2);

    echo "Registro inserido com sucesso. O último ID inserido é:" . $last_id;
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Não foi possível executar $query. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

// fecha conexão
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<!--
/* TABELAS */
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `db_demo`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_demo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabela_a`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_a` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `telefone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabela_b`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela_b` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `telefone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `tabela_a_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
-->
```